# How do I install Adobe Premiere Elements on a computer that's isolated from the Internet?

Tags: premiere-elements, setup

I want to install Adobe Premiere Elements 14 on a computer that's not connected to the Internet. I used version 3 back when it was current and it did the job, but I don't know what happened to the discs. I didn't have that problem then, however.

Some software insists on contacting the publisher's server,  but they often provide for substitute validation. Does Adobe offer an alternative validation for air-gapped computers?

Comment: Apologies for what I would think is a duplicate, but I searched and couldn't find an existing question about this with the search terms I could think of.

Comment: This is really a question you should ask Adobe.  It's not really a production-related question.

Comment: I have found most large software companies difficult to reach, particularly with issues that they think are covered in their web FAQ. Adobe licensing practices are notoriously user-hostile, so I anticipated that asking them would not be helpful. But I can try. I thought that getting a video production workstation working is a production-related question, but I'm new to this part of Stack Exchange.

Comment: I just did a super-simple google search and hit this page: https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/internet-connection-creative-cloud-apps.html

Comment: Looks like [offline activation](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2219022) is a thing for Elements, even if error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Using Google, a popular internet search engine, [the Adobe help page that discusses this topic](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/internet-connection-creative-cloud-apps.html) is easily discovered.  In particular, it explains:

> You must connect to the Internet when you want to install Adobe Creative Cloud apps, such as Photoshop and Illustrator. Once the apps are installed on your computer, you don’t need an ongoing Internet connection to use the apps.
>
> You can use the apps in offline mode with a valid software license for a limited period. The apps attempt to validate your software license every 30 days. You receive a reminder to reconnect to the Internet to validate your license...

You can read more details on that web page and decide whether or not your online/offline behavior fits within those parameters or not.

Comment: That doesn't mention Premiere Elements, unless something else on the site says that Premiere Elements is a part of Creative Cloud. But thanks for the advice to try Google. I never would have thought of that.